# FAQ's URL for any SE Site?

Tags: support, api

Since I cannot find anything relevant in the API (I guess /stats endpoint would be most relevant):
Is it safe to assume that every SE Site has its FAQ at location: site_url/faq ?

Comment: Not an official answer, but I would say it is probably safe to depend on this URL being the same on all SE sites.

Comment: @George Thanks for your input. Hopefully, if this pattern ever changes, there will be a redirection to some new location.